# The fastest way to hide all labels in Gmail?

Tags: gmail-labels

Label is a great feature to organize mail messages in Gmail.

Currently I have quite too many labels that I want to hide them all and display back one by one by my choices.

My google search [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=gmail%20quickly%20hide%20all%20labels) is not very helpful. All I can find is going to `Setting in Gmail`, `tab Label` and show/hide each label manually; which is very tiring.

I want quickly hide all of them, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly we have it as built-in in `Gmail Label Setting`

[image]